# Why would a node not have shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am setting up a small elasticsearch cluster and one of the nodes does not get any shards. It works, is part of the cluster - just empty (`eu2` in the screenshot of `head` below):

[image]

This node is a worker, the only difference in the configuration vs. the other nodes are the lines

```
node.master: false
node.data: true
```

Is there a specific action which needs to be taken in order to have it populated with shards?

Comment: Have you tried moving a shard there?

Comment: @GregL: no, but shouldn't that be automatic? All the other nodes got shards automatically (without any action from my side)

Comment: Cluster balancing is automatic, but you can force shards to move between nodes if you wish. Try it and see if it sticks. What about when you shut down a node? Does `eu2` get any shards then? Also, check the settings for the nodes (`/_nodes` URL) to make sure they match and that shard allocation is enabled on `eu2`.

Comment: I found the problem. When testing the rerouting API it reported why a shard move was not successful. The failed part was about the version of elasticsearch on `eu2` (it was lower that the others). Upgrading it immediately fixed the problem, thanks. If you cold turn your useful comment about moving shards into an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try forcing a shard to move to the node in question.

If it does and sticks there, check your your shard allocation settings.

If it doesn't, check the logs to see why it won't go.

Comment: The move generated an error and the key infprmation was `[NO(target node version [1.6.2-SNAPSHOT] is older than source node version [1.7.1])]`. Upgrading fixed the issue.